# AWS EC2 instance not able to connect to bitbucket.org

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, bitbucket

`EC2 Details:
OS: Ubuntu 16.04
Git client: git version 2.7.4`

**Issue:**

From AWS instance I am not able to connect to bitbucket.org repositories. Tried ping to bitbucket.org but, I didn't got any response. I check-out bit-bucket repository via ssh clone. Outbound traffic is of type 'All traffic'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're facing the same issue from EU Frankfurt zone of AWS. However, it works well from EU Ireland AWS zone. So it seems to be specific to Frankfurt region.

Also there is a related mention in twitter - https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&q=frankfurt%20network%20bitbucket&src=typd

---

**UPDATE:**

You can see the official status here - https://status.bitbucket.org/

Currently it says: "Bitbucket is unavailable to customers routing from EU"

Comment: Hi I am facing this issues in Asia Pacific (Mumbai) region.

Comment: Same Issue in Mumbai aws servers

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem on my ec2 instance.

tried `ping bitbucket.org` packet loss : 100%'

I can't pull in any of my instacne but can pull in my local machine.
Dunno what is the problem.

Comment: Hi Ravi vasoya, thanks for your reply, i am facing this issues from last 3 hours, also done traceroute also not able find the bitbucket route path.

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems to be solved now by bitbucket.
-thnks bitbucket team

Answer (score 0):

in AWS security group check whether port 443 is configured for https connections